# Why is Benson a gumball machine in Regular Show?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, regular-show

Most of the main characters on the *Regular Show* are organic, anthropomorphized, animal-like creatures. And then there's Benson; the humanoid gumball machine. I don't get it. Why is he a gumball machine? Why does a gumball machine have arms and legs and become more than an inanimate object?

[image: Benson]

Comment: Because cartoons

Comment: @sanpaco Yes, cartoons. But surely there is some kind of explanation in an early episode or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was never an explanation in the show as far I can remember, but the creater (J.G. Quintel) of the regular show had already played around with the idea of a humanoid gumball machine before. In his student film [2 in the AM PM](http://regularshow.wikia.com/wiki/2_in_the_AM_PM) there are two characters that take drug laced candy which turns them into Benson and Mordecai, characters we know from Regular Show.

I don't think there is currently a reason as to why Benson is a gumball machine, it's just the cartoon world, everything is possible. It's more likely that Quintel is paying homage to his earlier work, but until he speaks out about this, we won't know for sure.

Comment: It should also be noted that this is possibly a recurring theme in the series as Gene, the manager of a rival park, is a vending machine.